# Content view is not updating when the variable is changed

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have basic app that display a website and when I press a button it should send me to another link but it does not idk why I tried using @state bool and changing it when button is pressed but no use
the website loads but the button does not change the website

ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedSegment = 0
    @State var websi = "172.20.10.3"
    @State private var websites = ["192.168.8.125", "192.168.8.125/Receipts.php","192.168.8.125/myqr.php"]
    @State private var sssa = ["Home","MyRecipts","MyQr"]
    @State var updater: Bool
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            NavigationView{
                
                VStack{
                    Button(action: {
                        self.websi = "172.20.10.3/myqe.php"
                        self.updater.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Button"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    } .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle());
                   
                              
                               
                                 
                                /* Text("Selected value is: \(websites[selectedSegment])").padding()*/
                      
                  Webview(url: "http://\(websi)")
                    
                }
            }
            .padding(.top, -44.0)

        }
       
    }
    
}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView( updater: false)
            .padding(.top, -68.0)
    }
}
```

Webview.swift

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct Webview: UIViewRepresentable {
    var url: String
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        guard let url = URL(string: self.url) else{
            return WKWebView()
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let wkWebView = WKWebView()
        wkWebView.load(request)
        return wkWebView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context:
        UIViewRepresentableContext<Webview>){
        
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using an `@ObservableObject`:

```
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<WebView>) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<WebView>) {
        if let url = URL(string: viewModel.url) {
            webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        }
    }
}

extension WebView {
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var url: String

        init(url: String) {
            self.url = url
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var currentWebsite = "https://google.com"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Change") {
                self.currentWebsite = "https://apple.com"
            }
            WebView(viewModel: .init(url: currentWebsite))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I refresh web view without losing data

Comment: @ShimmyOps I updated my answer - now the WebView reloads urls correctly.

Comment: I tried this it works but now the webcam in my site don't load the picture In my site any ideas why? when I used the old reload it works perfectly

Comment: @ShimmyOps No, I don't know what you're doing. It works fine for the Google/Apple pages.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not recalling the WebView when the websi changes it won't do anything. You need to add a @Binding tag to the url so that it knows to update. Then you can call

```
WebView(self.$websi)
```

Comment: how can I reload web view without losing data